# Jasmin : How to mock @ViewChild component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, viewchild

i'm trying to test a component with child components which are also stored as `@ViewChild`

**project-estimation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectCreateComponent } from './project-create/project-create.component';
import { ProjectCaracComponent } from './project-carac/project-carac.component';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-estimation',
  templateUrl: './project-estimation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-estimation.component.css']
})
export class ProjectEstimationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild(ProjectCreateComponent, {static: false}) createComp: ProjectCreateComponent;
  @ViewChild(ProjectCaracComponent, {static: false}) caracComp: ProjectCaracComponent;

  public isCreateStepCompleted = false;
  public isCaracStepCompleted = false;
  private subTokens: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit() {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.subTokens.push(this.createComp.projectTypeForm.statusChanges
      .subscribe((status) => {
      this.isCreateStepCompleted = this.isFormStatusValid(status);
    }));

    this.subTokens.push(this.caracComp.projectCaracForm.statusChanges
      .subscribe((status) => {
      this.isCaracStepCompleted = this.isFormStatusValid(status);
    }));
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for (const token of this.subTokens) {
      token.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  public isFormStatusValid(status: string) {
    return status === 'VALID';
  }
}
```

**project-estimation.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>
    <p>Estimation de projet</p>
  </mat-card-title>

  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
        <mat-step id="createStep" [completed]="isCreateStepCompleted">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Créez votre projet</ng-template>
          <app-project-create></app-project-create>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step id="caracStep" [completed]="isCharacStepCompleted">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Définissez les characteristiques</ng-template>
          <app-project-charac></app-project-charac>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step id="quotationStep" [completed]="isQuotationStepCompleted">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Récupérez votre estimation</ng-template>
          <app-project-quotation></app-project-quotation>
        </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Now i want to set a non regression test to be sure that if one of the child component emits statusChanges, the status is correctly updated.

Here is the test i tried to set up

**project-estimation.components.spect.ts**

```
class FormGroupMock {

  public status: string;
  public statusChanges: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  public constructor() {

    this.status = 'VALID';
    this.statusChanges = new BehaviorSubject(this.status);
  }

  public setStatus(status: string): void {
    this.status = status;
    this.statusChanges.next(this.status);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-create',
  template: ''
})
class CreateCompMockComponent {
  public projectTypeForm = new FormGroupMock();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-carac',
  template: ''
})
class CaracCompMockDComponent {
  public projectCaracForm = new FormGroupMock();
}

describe('ProjectEstimationComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectEstimationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectEstimationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(testProjectEstimationRoutes),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        DummyComponent,
        CreateCompMockComponent,
        CaracCompMockDComponent,
        ProjectEstimationComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectEstimationComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

However when i run this test i get :

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectTypeForm' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectTypeForm' of undefined
    at ProjectEstimationComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/project-estimation/project-estimation.component.ts:32:41)
...
```

So as you can see, the mock components are not used as ViewChild for the main component.
**How can i fix this so i can use those mock components** in order to write more complex test like this :

```
it('should listen for sub component changes', () => {
    const createComp: CreateCompMockComponent = TestBed.get(ProjectCreateComponent);
    const caracComp: CaracCompMockDComponent = TestBed.get(ProjectCaracComponent);

    expect(component.isCreateStepCompleted).toBe(true);
    expect(component.isCaracStepCompleted).toBe(true);

    createComp.projectTypeForm.setStatus('INVALID');
    caracComp.projectCaracForm.setStatus('INVALID');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.isCreateStepCompleted).toBe(false);
    expect(component.isCaracStepCompleted).toBe(false);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Unit Testing @ViewChild](https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild) will show you an example of how to do this, specifically in the section `Adding a provider to the stub component`.
Basically your mock will need to provide itself, which then allows your test to create the viewChild as you would expect.

```
class FormGroupMock {

  public status: string;
  public statusChanges: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  public constructor() {

    this.status = 'VALID';
    this.statusChanges = new BehaviorSubject(this.status);
  }

  public setStatus(status: string): void {
    this.status = status;
    this.statusChanges.next(this.status);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-create',
  template: '<div></div>',
  providers: [{ provide: ProjectCreateComponent, useClass: CreateCompMockComponent }],
})
class CreateCompMockComponent {
  public projectTypeForm = new FormGroupMock();

  setStatus(status: string): void {

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-charac',
  template: '<div></div>',
  providers: [{ provide: ProjectCaracComponent, useClass: CaracCompMockDComponent }],
})
class CaracCompMockDComponent {
  public projectCaracForm = new FormGroupMock();

  setStatus(status: string): void {

  }
}

fdescribe('ProjectEstimationComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectEstimationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectEstimationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // MaterialModule,
        // RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(testProjectEstimationRoutes),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        // DummyComponent,
        CreateCompMockComponent,
        CaracCompMockDComponent,
        ProjectEstimationComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
      ],

    })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectEstimationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should listen for sub component changes', () => {
    // these don't work at the moment, but that can be fixed more easily  
    expect(component.isCreateStepCompleted).toBe(true);
    expect(component.isCaracStepCompleted).toBe(true);

    component.createComp.setStatus('INVALID');
    component.caracComp.setStatus('INVALID');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.isCreateStepCompleted).toBe(false);
    expect(component.isCaracStepCompleted).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Here is where I trimmed down your html to only the affected components. You can start adding back as you deem fit.

```
<app-project-create></app-project-create>

<app-project-charac></app-project-charac>
```

Comment: I tried this solution already (and i just tried again) but i still get :
```Failed: Template parse errors:
'app-project-create' is not a known element:
```

Comment: Odd. That indicates that you aren't putting them in the declarations of your TestBed. The selectors should match the component they are mocking, so if that is something other than 'app-project-create' then you'll want to update the mock to have the same selector as your real component.

Comment: I will update my question to include the html but as you will see, the selectors are the same

Comment: When trying this locally I get something different, but I think I'm using a much newer version of Angular Material. When I knock down the html to just those two components of yours it gets a different result.

Comment: Do you have a something working as i expect or do you have a different error ?

Comment: Updated with what I had working locally - the html I trimmed down to not include the angular material, I think it may be causing an issue. It also seems that your current material version is old, may or may not be affecting this.

Comment: I still get the error ```Failed: Template parse errors: 'app-project-create' is not a known element:```. Also, why do you think i have an old version of angular material ?

Comment: The newer version has split the modules into many different ones, and you're only importing the one. When I downloaded the latest version I had to import three or four module files before I axed material altogether.

Comment: The material module i imported is one that i created myself. It is the module which import and export every material module that i need.
This solution comes from a tutorial from [Code-maze](https://code-maze.com/get-started-angular-material/#creatingmaterialmodule)